# Comparing data in record with the user's input?

Tags: ada

Updated question. In this code, I have defined a record type that holds a bunch of data for a specific species. I want to write an if statement that compares the user's input for "Specied_Type" with the data that already exists in "Species_Type (Human, Elf, ....)". Any suggestions?

My code:

```
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;              use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;          use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with  Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;      use Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;

procedure Hero is
type Species_Type is(Human, Elf, Lizardman, Halfling);  --Line 8
type Eye_Type is (Blue, Green, Brown, Gray, Black);
package Species_Type_IO is new Enumeration_IO (Species_Type); 
use Species_Type_IO;
package Eye_Type_IO is new Enumeration_IO (Eye_Type); use Eye_Type_IO;
 
type Hero_Type is       
  record
     Name: Unbounded_String;
     Age: Integer;
     Gender:Unbounded_String;
     weight: Float;
     Haircolor: Unbounded_String;
     Species: Species_Type;
     Eyecolor: Eye_Type;
  end record;
 A: Hero_Type;

Procedure Get(Item: out Hero_Type) is 
begin
  Put("Name: "); Item.Name:= Get_Line;
  Put_Line("Name: " & Item.Name);
   Put("Age: "); Get(Item.Age); Put("Age: " & Integer'Image (Item.Age)); 
  New_Line;
  Put("Species: "); Get(Item.Species); Put("Species: "); 
  Put(Item.Species, set => Lower_Case); New_Line;
  Put("Eye color: "); Get(Item.Eyecolor); Put_Line("Color: 
  "&Eye_Type'Image(Item.Eyecolor));
  
  if Item.Species /= A.Species then  --Does not seem right
     Put("Wrong input"); end if;
                       
begin
Get(A);
end Hero;
```

Comment: You never instantiate an Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO for the type Species. The compiler has no Get procedure for an instance of Species. Why does your Get procedure have a parameter of Hero_Type but it only references the instance named A defined in the enclosing scope? Within the Get procedure change all references to A into references of Item.

Comment: Tnx. It worked. Now I got another idea. I have just updated my question (hope it's ok) and I want to write an if statement that compares the user's input for Species_Type with the data that already exists in "Species_Type(Human, elf, ....)". Do not know how to right the if statement(or loop) for it.

Comment: When using Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO instantiated for Species the Get procedures will raise Data_Error if the user input is not one of the values in the Species enumeration. You should handle Data_Error and re-prompt the user for a correct input.

Comment: Yes.  when Data_Error =>
         Put_Line ("Invalid input -- please try again.");                                                           Can I use it for all data in "Get"  instead of writing it over and over again after each input?.  Where should i put the loop? outside or inside the "Get"?

Comment: You can write your own input function which calls Get and handles the exception, eventually returning a valid value of Species.

Comment: "Does not seem right" is not very informative. What do you expect and what do you get? Note that in your only call to Get, Item and A are the same object, if Hero_Type is passed by reference, as is likely, so your test would always succeed.